# How to load ES6 modules separately (as-needed) aka. Tree Shaking?

Tags: node.js, webpack, create-react-app, es6-modules

Right now I'm going through my application, changing instances of this pattern:

```
import {Grid, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap'
```

into:

```
import {Grid, Row, Col} from '../react-bootstrap'
```

where `react-bootstrap.js` is a simple file at the root of my project, with a selective import of the ES6 modules I need from that NPM package:

```
import Grid  from 'react-bootstrap/es/Grid'
import Col   from 'react-bootstrap/es/Col'
import Row   from 'react-bootstrap/es/Row'

export {Grid, Col, Row}
```

Doing this for a number of packages, I was able to reduce my bundle file size by more than 50%.

**Is there a WebPack module or plugin that can do it automatically for any package?**

If this transformation (that is, only including in the bundle what is explicitly imported, instead of the entire library) was applied recursively to the entire package tree, I bet we would see a dramatic size difference.

---

Edit: as **Swivel** points out, this is known as [Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/) and is supposed to be performed automatically by Webpack 3+ with UglifyJSPlugin, which is included in the [production configuration from react-scripts](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js) that I'm using.

I'm not sure if this is a bug in either of those projects, but I'm seeing big size gains by doing selective imports manually, which shouldn't be the case if Tree Shaking was being performed.

Comment: What version of `webpack` are you using? Version 3+ has `Tree Shaking`, which should eliminate all unused / unwanted / unreachable code in modules. (e.g., it should do exactly what you're doing right now).

Comment: @Swivel I'm using `create-react-app` which uses Webpack 3.8.1. [The production configuration](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.prod.js) uses `UglifyJSPlugin` which *should* perform dead code removal, but does not seem to. Do you think I should report it as a bug to `create-react-app`?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever tool that would be would be equivalent to implementing tree shaking, and it would need to be integrated into your bundler. So, no.

For the record, dead code elimination is *not* the same thing as tree shaking. Tree shaking is breaking unused dependencies between modules. Dead code elimination is within a single module. Uglify.js only knows about one module at a time, so it cannot do tree shaking: it just does dead code elimination. So the fact that you are using the `UglifyJSPlugin` is irrelevant to whether or not your build environment has tree shaking.